# Should Questions Regarding Program Management be Included in the List of On-Topic or Off-Topic Questions?

Tags: discussion, beta, questions, asking-questions

**[Program Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_management)** is a field that -- on the surface -- appears to have a lot in common with [Project Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management).  The Wikipedia defines Program Management as encompassing one or more projects.  In addition, programs are typically ongoing whereas projects typically have a clear cut start and end date.

- Should the FAQ address Program Management questions and make allowances/disallowances for them?
- What additional guidelines will be necessary if program management questions are included as on-topic questions?
- What reasons should program management questions be **excluded**?
- What reasons should program management questions be **included**?

Comment: Do people see there being a distinct skill-set difference between project and program management, or is there just a difference in scale with the ensuring complexities?

Comment: The skillsets may be different in that program managers should in theory be even less concerned with details than a project manager would.  In short, seeing the bigger picture and thinking more strategic than tactical may come in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - What reasons should program management questions be **excluded?**

It's odd that the program managers have not surfaced in these forums. I have not seen a call for this subject either implicitly or explicitly. There are currently no Area 51 proposals citing an interest in "program management" nor are there any questions on this site veering into program management — so the desire/need for this subject is simply hypothetical. That would hardly make it FAQ-worthy.

> - What reasons should program management questions be **included?**

If a need for program management questions *were* to surface, I would almost certainly insist that they be incorporated into *this* site.

So, I have no objections to adding it to the FAQ. I would like to see the expansion of this site into related areas. But, practically speaking, the issue of whether or not program management is mentioned explicitly in the FAQ is either moot or rhetorical.

Comment: Makes sense.  Even if it's not in the FAQ, I do think it's a good idea for those of us who are early adopters of this site to have clear communication as to what the expectations are. If and when a program manager question surfaces, we'll be more prepared to handle the question of whether or not it belongs. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also, how come your rep never goes up?  I noticed that doesn't happen with moderators on other sites?

Comment: @jmort253: Meta posts do not gain rep. Your meta "reputation" is derived from the parent site.

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to see a future with:

> "Offtopic, your question is about
>   **program** management, and this site is
>   about **project** management."

Let's allow both on this site.